# Sorting ArrayList according to date

Tags: java, date, datetime, arraylist, collections

I've been learning the language for the past 1 month. I have recently finished learning the basic of the Date class. I have an array list, which I have to order according to date. However, the values of the date are changing. Using LocalTime throws the NumberExceptionError even though the DateTimeFormatter pattern was set as required, in MM-dd-yyyy. **I could use some help in understanding as to why the dates that are taken shown in the output don't match with my input.** Furthermore, how do I print just the Date? I don't need the time.

Here is the code:

THE MATCHING CLASS

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.time.*;
public class DateCompare implements Comparable<Match> {
    private Date matchDate;
    public Date getMatchDate() {
        return matchDate;
    }
    public void setMatchDate(Date matchDate) {
        this.matchDate = matchDate;
    }
        public Match(Date matchDate) {

    this.matchDate = matchDate;

    }

public int compareTo(Match m)
{
    if(matchDate.before(m.matchDate))
        return -1;
    else if(matchDate.after(m.matchDate))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("\nMatch held on "+matchDate);
}
```

}

THE MAIN CLASS

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.text.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));     //INPUTCONSOLE
        ArrayList<DateCompare> arraylist=new ArrayList<>();     //ARRAYLIST DECLARATION
        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements");//NO OF ELEMENTS
        Integer no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        SimpleDateFormat b=new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-YYYY"); //TAKING INPUT IN MM-dd-yyyy

        for(int i=0;i<no;i++)                   //Loop to take in the values
        {
            System.out.println("Enter match date in (MM-dd-yyyy)");
            String dateInput=br.readLine();
            Date date=(Date) b.parse(a);
            arraylist.add(new DateCompare(date));       //Adding the values to the object in the arraylist
        }

        Collections.sort(al);                       //Sorting the collection based on date
        Iterator<Match> x=al.iterator();
        while(x.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(x.next());            //Printing the objects after sorting
        }


    }

}
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter the number of matches
02
Enter match date in (MM-dd-yyyy)
12-11-2011

Enter match date in (MM-dd-yyyy)
12-18-2012


SORTED MATCHES(Based on Date)

Match held on Sun Dec 26 00:00:00 IST 2010
Match held on Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2012
```

When I posted a question here the last time, I was told to make the code easily readable. I hope I've done that.

Comment: You should learn the `java.time` package instead. The `Date` class is pretty much obsolete, and you should never use it in any new code. Also as you've noticed, the `Date` object represents a datetime, unlike for example a `LocalDate`, which represents just a date.

Comment: `Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2012` is the default `toString()` pattern for `Date` class. You can change the output with `new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-YYYY").format(date);`. Then it will only print `01-01-2012`

Comment: Btw, your class names and variable names don't match in your code. Class `Match` doesn't exist, only `Datecompare`. Also `arraylist` variable doesn't exist, only `al`

Comment: also you should only import classes that you actually need and not whole packages

Comment: The class of the object that is added to the ArrayList need to implement the Comparable interface. In your case `Match` class.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: Fixed the names. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You’ve posted very much code. Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead, please?

Comment: [`Date.compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)) exists for a reason!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Date.compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)) method when applicable (Date has one that works pretty well)

To display a date with a specific format, use a date formater (SimpleDateFormat for instance)

And as @Kayaman said, if possible, use the Java 8 Time API